# corruption of the heap, error in C

Tags: c, debugging, heap-memory

well I dont need to explain too much, this function get this error at the line I marked all the time, only in this function there are allocations of memoery, please help me find out where is the issue...(read some other topics with that here, but nothing helped me solve it)
ERROR:"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in sapProject.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in sapProject.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
"

```
void storeTok(char * lexem,int line,enum keywords typeof)
{
    int ind;
    if(tokens.size%100==0)
    {
    if(tokens.size==0)
    {
    tokens.ptrInd=-1;
    tokens.first=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    tokens.first->back = NULL;
    tokens.first->next = NULL;
    tokens.last=tokens.first;
    }
    else
    {
    node * nodenz=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); /error is here
    nodenz->back = tokens.last;
    nodenz->next = NULL;
    tokens.last->next=nodenz;
    tokens.last=tokens.last->next;
    tokens.last=nodenz;
    }
    }

    // general




ind=tokens.size-(tokens.size/100)*100;
tokens.last->tokens[ind].type=typeof;
tokens.last->tokens[ind].linen=line;
tokens.last->tokens[ind].lexema=lexem;
tokens.size++;
}
```

Thanks!

edit(except this, there is also a header(and thats it..):

```
typedef struct token
{
    char * lexema ;
    int linen;
    enum keywords type;
}token;

typedef struct node
{
    struct node * next,*back;
    token tokens [50];
}node;

typedef struct LL
{
    struct node * last, *first, * ptr;
    int size,ptrInd;
}LL;

LL tokens;

void storeTok(char * lexem,int line,enum keywords typeof);
```

main func:

```
void main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<26;++i)
    {
storeTok("blabla",1,END);
storeTok("sdfasd",1,START);
storeTok("sfadds",1,IF);
storeTok("gvdfd",1,THEN);
storeTok("dfsfd",1,ELSE);
    }
    storeTok("dfsfd",1,EOF_);
}
```

Comment: Then let me not explain my downvote either.

Comment: @GhostCat please explain :) ,
is it beceause you dont like people asking questions?

Comment: Just read the message that comes with : your question put on hold.

Comment: lol, if anyone acrually needed a reason, your indentation makes it difficult to read/follw your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is probably the victim. The code that corrupted the heap is elsewhere. You can use a tool like valgrind or a similar tool to find it. (Or give us enough code to replicate the error and we can track it down for you.)

Comment: That would better be a comment; such question is subject to closure.

Comment: You're not supposed to answer the question in a comment, and this answers the question. (To the extent that there is a question.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz added the rest of the code(its just a header file..)

Comment: That's not enough to replicate the problem. The problem is in some other piece of code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but there is no other code.....

Comment: Then I can't see how it could corrupt the heap, since there's no `main` function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz added main, which is just calling the function....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141820/discussion-between-secret-and-david-schwartz).